# Add attribute to Select Option to pull additional data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select box to which I have a value against the options, I also want another value based on the selection.

**My select:**

```
<select class="form-control input-lg" id="credits">
    <option value="1" price="2">1 Credit</option>
    <option value="10" price="4">10 Credits</option>
    <option value="25" price="6">25 Credits</option>
    <option value="50" price="8">50 Credits</option>
    <option value="100" price="10">100 Credits</option>
    <option value="200" price="12">200 Credits</option>
</select>
<button id="top">Apply</button>
```

**My Javascript looking for the value of select:**

```
$(document).on('click', 'button#top', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var credits = $('select#credits').val();
    var value = $('select#credits').val($('option:selected').data('price'));
});
```

At the moment all I get on `alert()` is `Object[Object]`

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using Jquery's .attr() method instead of data? http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Also, do you want to change selected option text, or just to get value?

Comment: Hard to tell what you're trying to achieve but since you're using `.data('price')` I would say you better change `price=...` to `data-price=...`.

Comment: Also,  use console.log instead of alert

Answer (score 2):

`val()` will only get (or set) the actual `value`; never `price` or any other attribute.

And if you're going to use jQuery's `data()` method, you need to use `data-*` attributes.

Finally, there's no need to include the tag name (e.g. `select`) when using an `id`. `id`s are unique.

With that in mind:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#top', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var credits = $('#credits').val();
  
    // the + makes sure we get a numeric value
    var value = + $('#credits option:selected').data('price');
    console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control input-lg" id="credits">
    <option value="1" data-price="2">1 Credit</option>
    <option value="10" data-price="4">10 Credits</option>
    <option value="25" data-price="6">25 Credits</option>
    <option value="50" data-price="8">50 Credits</option>
    <option value="100" data-price="10">100 Credits</option>
    <option value="200" data-price="12">200 Credits</option>
</select>
<button id="top">Apply</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

target the selected option using `$('select#credits option:selected')` and then get the attribute price using `.attr('price')`

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button#top', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var credits = $('select#credits').val();
    var value = $('select#credits option:selected').attr('price');  
    alert(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control input-lg" id="credits">
    <option value="1" price="2">1 Credit</option>
    <option value="10" price="4">10 Credits</option>
    <option value="25" price="6">25 Credits</option>
    <option value="50" price="8">50 Credits</option>
    <option value="100" price="10">100 Credits</option>
    <option value="200" price="12">200 Credits</option>
</select>
<button id="top">Apply</button>
```